# Why is window.matchMedia callback called when not applying?

Tags: javascript, callback, media-queries

I am trying to adapt a simple set of media queries from css to javascript. The css definition works as expected, however, the javascript code does not.

The code blocks look as follows:

```
  window.matchMedia("(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)")
  .addListener( function() {
    console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 600px)");
    document.body.style.background = "red";
  });
```

Depending on the width, I change the document color. When I change the size of the window it seems that two callback functions are called: the one matching the former width, and the one matching the current width.

I would expect only the one matching the current width to be called.

For instance, when I change the browser size from `window.innerWidth` 1871 to `window.innerWidth` 700 the following happens:

```
window.innerWidth: 1871
CALLBACK (max-width: 800px)
CALLBACK (min-width: 801px)
window.innerWidth: 700
```

and the callback for `min-width` 801px is applied.

What am I doing wrong?

The full test code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script>

window.onresize = afterWindowResize;
function afterWindowResize(){
  showSize();
}

function x(){
  showSize();

  window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)")
  .addListener( function() {
    console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 400px)");
    document.body.style.background = "green";
  });

  window.matchMedia("(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)")
  .addListener( function() {
    console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 600px)");
    document.body.style.background = "red";
  });

  window.matchMedia("(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)")
  .addListener( function() {
    console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 800px)");
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
  });

  window.matchMedia("(min-width: 801px)")
  .addListener( function() {
    console.log("CALLBACK (min-width: 801px)");
    document.body.style.background = "gray";
  });
}

function showSize(){
  console.log("window.innerWidth: " + window.innerWidth); 
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="x()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the event and then use `matches` it will work properly

```
window.matchMedia("...").addListener( function(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

*Or you should be able to also use `this`, e.g. `if (this.matches) {...}`*

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
      window.onresize = afterWindowResize;

      function afterWindowResize() {
        showSize();
      }

      function x() {
        showSize();

        window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)")
          .addListener(function(e) {
            if (e.matches) {
              console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 400px)");
              document.body.style.background = "green";
            }
          });

        window.matchMedia("(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)")
          .addListener(function(e) {
            if (e.matches) {
              console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 600px)");
              document.body.style.background = "red";
            }
          });

        window.matchMedia("(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)")
          .addListener(function(e) {
            if (e.matches) {
              console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 800px)");
              document.body.style.background = "blue";
            }
          });

        window.matchMedia("(min-width: 801px)")
          .addListener(function(e) {
            if (e.matches) {
              console.log("CALLBACK (min-width: 801px)");
              document.body.style.background = "gray";
            }
          });
      }

      function showSize() {
        console.log("window.innerWidth: " + window.innerWidth);
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="x()">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stupid me. I implicitly assumed that the callback is called only if the condition matches. Thank you!